# Rendering on html5 canvas takes cosumes too much time, buffering barely helps

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

For a game, I'm trying to calculate light and shadows. For this, I break down my canvas into square areas and calculate, if a light ray would be blocked on the way from the player to each square position. I've managed now to reach a reasonably good performance for those calculations.

The results are then visualized by covering non-visible areas with dark squares (`Canvas.fillRect(...)`), but this step becomes too expensive when a want a nice resolution, i.e. ~10'000 squares for calculation. I've tried to first render them into an off-screen canvas (=buffer), then draw the buffer on my visible canvas, but I could not experience any remarkable performance improvement.

Is there something I missed, or are there other methods to fasten up drawing?

**Update:**

The affected code can be found here: https://github.com/otruffer/Ape_On_Tape/blob/master/src/client/js/visibility.js (Code is a bit too big to post here)

The actual drawing takes place in `drawCloudAt(...)` and `flushBuffer()` in the lower part of this file.

Comment: We'd need to see your code.

Comment: Okay, I added a link to the JS source file of our github project. Feel free to clone and run the game on your machine... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing real-time light calculation in software is always a performance killer. Did you consider using a real 3d engine instead which does the light calculation on the video card? Yes, Javascript can do that now - this new feature is called WebGL.

When you just need a faster way to apply your lightmap, you could manipulate the RGB values of your canvas directly instead of using fillRect. You can use getImageData to get an array of raw 8 bit RGBA values of your canvas. You can then manipulate this array and put it back with putImageData.

Comment: That sounds cool! I think WebGL might be a slight overkill, at least if it takes a lot effort to learn and build. But I will surely try manipulating raw RGB data, I hope it will be faster... Btw, can you say something about the support of WebGL in today's or tomorrow's browsers?

Comment: Wait, there is no such method as `setImageData()`, right..? Edit: It's actually called `putImageData()`. :D

Comment: Right, that's what it was called. I corrected that mistake in my answer.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach To ease some of the learning process for WebGL, consider having a look at the excellent three.js library http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/

Comment: Impressive! I'm just thinking about using WebGL, because manipulating the imageData array did not yield too much performance, in fact it's a bit slower because basically need to iterate over every pixel once to manipulate it...